# How to add ellipses on table body when data is coming from an object using Datatables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am learning JQuery Datatable and i have come across a scenario, where i need to implement ellipses on the data populating on table body for long text and on hover the complete text should display like a tooltip, I saw some sample that works if string is passed in data,[like this](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26), but i am passing an object.
Any help will be highly appreciated..

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Following is my code

controller:

```
paymentSearchGrid = $(".pods-search-table").DataTable({
"columns": $scope.header,
"data": $scope.tablebody,
"searchViewTable": false,
"bLengthChange": false, //disable page size selection
"pageLength": 100,
"colReorder": {
    fixedColumnsLeft: 1
},
"pagingType": "simple",
"scrollY": $(".right-panel>.scroll-area").height() - 120,
"pagingType": "simple",
"order": [
    [3, "desc"]
],
"scrollX": true,
"order": [
    [3, "asc"]
],
"searchable": true,
//"aLengthMenu": [[10,25, 50, 75, 100,125,150,175,200,-1], [10,25, 50, 75,100,125,150,175,200, "All"]],
"columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 0,
    "searchable": false,
    "orderable": false,
    "className": 'dt-body-center',
    "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
    }
},{

    "targets": [1],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false

}],
```

});

Object:

```
{
"abc" : 
[
0 : {
        "name" : "Transaction Reference Number",
        "short_name": "Transaction Ref",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    },
1 : {
        "name" : "Transaction Reference Number",
        "short_name": "Transaction Ref",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    },
2 : {
        "name" : "Transaction Reference Number",
        "short_name": "Transaction Ref",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",

    }
]
```

}

Comment: The best ellipsis option is with CSS  `text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap`. If you make with CSS, doesn't matter if it's a string, an object, or so on, the text on the cell will be cutted when it doesn't fit, and you don't need to know how many characters fits inside.

Comment: I agree with you Marcos, but for this approach i will ave to fix the column width which i dont want to

Comment: NO, you don't need to have the fixed width on the columns, just with `max-width` you can do it. I have tons of tables (datatables, jqgrids, and handmade tables) that uses CSS ellipsis. Sometimes you need the trick of `max-width: 0` on the cells, but is a single property, and you don't need to fight with javascript and the slower performance / errors / crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember where I stole this from if I didn't write it myself but this works within a render function really quite well:

```
function abbreviate(user_str, user_max, user_suffix) {
    var startend_spaces = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
    var linebreak_spaces = /[\r\n]*\s*[\r\n]+/g;
    var tab_spaces = /[ \t]+/g;
    var ending_space = /[ ]$/g;
    var abbr = '';
    var suffix = (typeof user_suffix !== 'undefined' ? user_suffix : '...');
    var max = user_max - suffix.length;
    var counter = 0;
    var string = user_str;
    var len;
    if ((string = string.replace(startend_spaces, '').replace(linebreak_spaces, ' ').replace(tab_spaces, ' ')).length <= max) {
        return string;
    }
    string = string.split(' ');
    len = string.length;
    while (counter < len) {
        // individual characters of a string can be accessed via bracket notation
        if ((abbr + string[counter]).length < max) {
            abbr += string[counter] + ' ';
        } else {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return abbr.replace(ending_space, '') + suffix;
}
```

I guess you'd need something like this in your columnsDefs array:

```
{

    "targets": [2],
    "render": function(d){
        return abbreviate(d, 30);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.